# Error when calling WCF webservice with java (Eclipse Axis Client)

Tags: java, eclipse, wcf, axis, webservice-client

I have a problem to call a web service. I used eclipse to create an Webservice client (new other->web service->web service client.

The client is generated well and I use the following code to start the client:

The service is called http://server/Servicename.svc?wdsl

```
IServicenameProxy ws = new IServicenameProxy();
try 
{
    String = "testid";
    String test = ws.getName(id);
    System.out.println(test);
} 
catch (RemoteException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

On the first row i get this error message:

> 2012-04-26 14:59:58,221 ERROR [logforj] Turbine.handleException: null
>       2012-04-26 14:59:58,221 ERROR [logforj] 
>       java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>           at org.apache.axis.handlers.BasicHandler.(BasicHandler.java:43)
>           at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getAxisClient(Service.java:104)
>           at org.apache.axis.client.Service.(Service.java:197)
>           at org.tempuri.MaskinorderLocator.(ServicenameLocator.java:21)
>       .....

Any Ideas?

Comment: please publish the full exception, there shold be an additional message. Also use Fiddler to see if axis actually sent anything to the service

Comment: Som additional stack trace: Caused by: org.apache.commons.discovery.DiscoveryException: No implementation defined for org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
 at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.ClassUtils.verifyAncestory(ClassUtils.java:176)
 at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.SPInterface.verifyAncestory(SPInterface.java:201)
 at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.SPInterface.newInstance(SPInterface.java:195)
 at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverClass.newInstance(DiscoverClass.java:579)

Comment: this sounds more like a warning (no logger), maybe there is another error. I suggest you try to build a proxy to some acis web service and see if that works. looks like a general axis usage issue rather then specific to this wcf service

Comment: The service was corrupt and this error was impossible to solve from this information